# libGdx and facebook

Tags: java, android, libgdx, facebook-android-sdk

I'm testing facebook login with libgdx project. In my project-level build.gradle file, I added the gdx-facebook dependency from [here](https://github.com/TomGrill/gdx-facebook/wiki/3.-Setup-gdx-facebook)

```
project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        ......
        ......
        compile "de.tomgrill.gdxfacebook:gdx-facebook-android:1.4.1"
    }
}
```

and added the following dependency in the Module:android build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
}
```

There is no error in such condition. But when I remove tomgrill dependency from project-build.gradle file, android studio show me the following alert and the project cannot run.

> Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality(e.g. editing,
>   debugging) will not work properly.

Why facebook dependency does not work without tomgrill gdx-facebook extension? What the problem is?

Comment: why `android` module artifact, injected in core module ??

Comment: @Aryan What do you mean? Will you please elaborate?

Comment: my mistake, I'm not facing any gradle issue when I inject Facebook sdk only

Comment: hopefully you've minimum sdk version 15 and `maven { url "https://maven.google.com/" }` in repo list

Comment: @Aryan The problem is I don't have maven { url "https://maven.google.com/" } in my repo. I created a new LibGDX project and tested again. Now it works perfectly without gdx-facebook extension. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artifact `facebook-android-sdk`  available in `mavenCentral` repository so you've to add  `mavenCentral()` in your project repositories list in root `build.gradle` file.

By default, In LibGDX projects `mavenCentral()` is in repo list.

Some transitive dependency in your project, Internally `facebook-android-sdk` using many support library like `annotations`, `customtabs`, `appcompat-v7`, `support-v4` and more..

These support libraries are available on Google's Maven repository so you need to include Google's Maven repository in your top-level `build.gradle` file :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()

        // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must instead use:
        // maven {
        //     url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // }
        // An alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
    }
}
```